# Cloning nodes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I fiddled my code here - https://jsfiddle.net/wxd2pw88/2/

### HTML

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="textbox"/> 
    <button type="button" id="addition" onclick="add()"> + </button>
    <button type="button" id="subtraction" onclick="sub()"> - </button>
    <div id="replace"></div>
</body>
```

### JS

```
window.add =  function() {
    var inpt = document.getElementById('textbox');
    var clone = inpt.cloneNode(false);
    inpt.parentNode.appendChild(clone);

    var button1 = document.getElementById('addition');
    button1.parentNode.appendChild(button1.cloneNode(true));

    var button2 = document.getElementById('subtraction');
    button2.parentNode.appendChild(button2.cloneNode(true)); 

    var div1 = document.getElementById('replace');
    div1.parentNode.appendChild(div1.cloneNode(false));
}

window.sub = function() {
    var clonedTextbox = document.querySelectorAll('#textbox');
    var clonedButton1 = document.querySelectorAll('#addition');
    var clonedButton2 = document.querySelectorAll('#subtraction');

    clonedTextbox[clonedTextbox.length-1].parentNode.removeChild(clonedTextbox[clonedTextbox.length-1]);
    clonedButton1[clonedButton1.length-1].parentNode.removeChild(clonedButton1[clonedButton1.length-1]);
    clonedButton2[clonedButton2.length-1].parentNode.removeChild(clonedButton2[clonedButton2.length-1]);
}
```

### CSS

```
input{
    margin: 0px;
}

div {
    margin: 3px;
}
```

Following are the problems I am facing:

1. Child nodes of the button type of no margin
2. When the "+" button is pressed, a new child node is created. I want only the last child to be able to do this. Currently, all the children as well as the parent are able to create children. I want only the last child's "+" button to be active. All other children and the parent's button should be disabled.
3. Whatever text I am entering in the textbox is also getting copied to the children. I think this is because of the clone method, so I tried to use the createElement method. The problem I faced when using that was that no child nodes were able to create children. Only the parent was able to create multiple child nodes.

Comment: Point #2 isn't clear to me.

Comment: @j08691 I edited my post. Is point #2 clear now

Comment: OK, so what should happen to the + button when new nodes are added if only the last should be able to clone? Should the previous + buttons be disabled or removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're overusing IDs, they must be unique, so I changed them to classes.

Second, added a variable to keep track of the number of clones so would be easier to access the last one.

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/xm1jc8tu/3/)

```
var numClones = 0;

window.add = function () {
    var inpt = document.querySelectorAll('.textbox')[numClones];
    var clone = inpt.cloneNode(false);
    clone.value = "";
    inpt.parentNode.appendChild(clone);

    var button1 = document.querySelectorAll('.addition')[numClones];
    button1.parentNode.appendChild(button1.cloneNode(true));

    var button2 = document.querySelectorAll('.subtraction')[numClones];
    button2.parentNode.appendChild(button2.cloneNode(true));

    button1.disabled = true;
    button2.disabled = true;

    var div1 = document.querySelectorAll('.replace')[numClones];
    div1.parentNode.appendChild(div1.cloneNode(false));
    numClones++;
}

window.sub = function () {
    var clonedTextbox = document.querySelectorAll('.textbox')[numClones];
    var clonedButton1 = document.querySelectorAll('.addition')[numClones];
    var clonedButton2 = document.querySelectorAll('.subtraction')[numClones];

    clonedTextbox.parentNode.removeChild(clonedTextbox);
    clonedButton1.parentNode.removeChild(clonedButton1);
    clonedButton2.parentNode.removeChild(clonedButton2);

    numClones--;

    if (numClones >= 0) {
        var lastAdd = document.querySelectorAll('.addition')[numClones];
        var lastSub = document.querySelectorAll('.subtraction')[numClones];
        lastAdd.disabled = false;
        lastSub.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

And the extra space is for the line break, just put them right after the other instead of new line.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer your #2 point I've looked at you jsfiddle and made this solution:

```js
window.add =  function(element) {
 var inpt = element.previousElementSibling;
 var clone = inpt.cloneNode(false);
    clone.value = ''; //Question #3
 inpt.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
 var button1 = element;
 button1.parentNode.appendChild(button1.cloneNode(true));

 var button2 = element.nextElementSibling;
 button2.parentNode.appendChild(button2.cloneNode(true)); 
    button2.setAttribute('disabled','disabled')
    button1.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');

 var div1 = document.getElementById('replace');
 div1.parentNode.appendChild(div1.cloneNode(false));
}

window.sub = function() {
 var clonedTextbox = document.querySelectorAll('#textbox');
 var clonedButton1 = document.querySelectorAll('#addition');
 var clonedButton2 = document.querySelectorAll('#subtraction');

 clonedTextbox[clonedTextbox.length-1].parentNode.removeChild(clonedTextbox[clonedTextbox.length-1]);
 clonedButton1[clonedButton1.length-1].parentNode.removeChild(clonedButton1[clonedButton1.length-1]);
 clonedButton2[clonedButton2.length-1].parentNode.removeChild(clonedButton2[clonedButton2.length-1]);
    
    //remove disabled
    clonedButton2[clonedButton2.length-2].removeAttribute('disabled');
    clonedButton1[clonedButton1.length-2].removeAttribute('disabled');
}
```

```css
input{
 margin: 0px;
}

div {
 margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <input type="text" id="textbox"/> 
    <button type="button" id="addition" onclick="add(this)"> + </button>
    <button type="button" id="subtraction" onclick="sub(this)"> - </button>
    <div id="replace"></div>
</body>
```

Regarding your #1 and #3 point I'll take a look at it when I can.

### EDIT 1:

Solved the #3 by resetting the clone value.

Notes:

1. You are using the same `ID's`, and they should be unique!
2. This solution is using yours as a base, but there is simplest ways to do it. And some answers here highlight those.

Comment: What do you mean by, "You are using the same `ID's`, and they should be unique!" - I have used different `ID's` for the two buttons, "+" and "-"

Comment: An `ID` should be unique to an element. And by cloning elements like this you are cloning the `ID` so you end up having 2 elements with the same `ID`. That will cause some problems in HTML and JS. So if you manage to change them to class instead of id would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? In my version it is like this that you can only remove when at least 1 is there, and you can only click add on the last one.

If you want to disable it, i guess you could change the css a bit instead ;)

```js
var templateRow, content;

function removeLast()
{
    var children = content.children || [], 
        index = (children.length || 0) - 1;
    if (children.length > 0) {
        children[index].className = children[index].className.replace(/last/g, '');
    }
}

function setLast()
{
    var children = content.children || [], 
        index = (children.length || 0) - 1;
    if (children.length > 0) {
        children[index].className += ' last';
    }
}

function add() {
    removeLast();
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.innerHTML = templateRow;
    el.className = 'inputrow';
    if (content.children.length === 0) {
        el.className += ' first';
    }
    content.appendChild(el);
    setLast();
}

function retract(el) {
    var parent = el.parentNode;
    content.removeChild(parent);
    setLast();
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    templateRow  = document.getElementById('rowtemplate').innerHTML;
    content = document.getElementById('entire');
    add();
});
```

```css
.inputrow .input {
    margin: 0;
}
.inputrow button {
    margin: 3px;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.first .remove-button
{
    display: none;
}
.add-button 
{
    display: none;
}
.last .add-button
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<template class="hidden" id="rowtemplate"><input type="text" name="textbox" /><button type="button" class="add-button" onclick="add();">+</button><button type="button" class="remove-button" onclick="retract(this);">-</button></template>
<div id="entire"></div>
```

Comment: That was helpful. Can you tell me why do we need this: content.children || []

Comment: oh, just in case content.children is null or undefined (which shouldn't be) it's at least an empty array and then the length count can also go :)

Answer (score 0):

First, ince you're cloning elements, they can't have an ID since duplicate IDs are not allowed in HTML/JS.

SInce you're not using jQuery, I assume you can't/don't want to use it, some I will use plain JS.

I will also assume it's a requirement to use [DOM0 event attachements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510755/understanding-dom0-event-model-of-javascript) (directly in the HTML) instead of the more modern [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) way.

Easieest way to achieve this is to use some kind of delegated events. Instead of working with the elements themselves, you can wrap them in a container and use that container as a replica point.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/h4bx2jsh/)

### HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" class="textbox"/> 
        <button type="button" class="addition" onclick="add.call(this)">+</button>
        <button type="button" class="subtraction" onclick="sub.call(this)">-</button>
        <div class="replace"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

### Javascript

```
window.add =  function() {
    var addBtn = this,
        cnt = addBtn.parentNode,
        delBtn = cnt.getElementsByClassName('subtraction')[0],
        clone = cnt.cloneNode(true);

    // duplicate box
    cnt.parentNode.appendChild(clone);

    //hide buttons from this box
    addBtn.style.display = 'none';
    delBtn.style.display = 'none';
}

window.sub = function() {
    var cnt = this.parentNode,
        sibling = cnt.previousElementSibling;

    // show buttons from previous sibling
    sibling.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].style.display = 'inline-block';
    sibling.getElementsByTagName('button')[1].style.display = 'inline-block';

    //delete this box
    cnt.parentNode.removeChild(cnt);    
}
```

### Note

Notice I'm using `onclick="add.call(this)"` so that the function is called in context, passing the node the event is attached to as a param to the function.